# Mapping function with specific string in Pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

Here is my attempt.

The Dataframe I have now has a column which will decide how to deal with the features.

For example, `df` has two columns, `DATA` and `TYPE`. The `TYPE` has three classes: `S1`,`S2` and `S3`. And I will define three different function based on the different type of samples.

```
#### S1
 def f_s1(data):
     result = data+1
     return result

#### S2
 def f_s2(data):
     result = data+2
     return result

#### S3
 def f_s3(data):
     result = data+3
     return result
```

I also created a mapping set:

```
f_map= {'S1':f_s1,'S2':f_s2, 'S3': f_s3}
```

Then, I use pandas.Map utility to map these function with the type of each sample.

```
df['result'] = df['TYPE'].map(f_map)(df['DATA'])
```

But It didn't work with `TypeError: 'Series' object is not callable`.

Any advice would be appreciate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`df['TYPE'].map(f_map)` creates a series of functions, and if you want to apply them to your data column correspondingly, one option would be to use `zip()` function as follows:

```
df['result'] = [func(data) for func, data in zip(df['TYPE'].map(f_map), df['DATA'])]
df
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can group by `TYPE` and then apply the specific function for each type(or group) to the `DATA` column in that group, assuming your predefined functions contain vectorized operation and thus accepting series as parameters:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'TYPE':['S1', 'S2', 'S3', 'S1'], 'DATA':[1, 1, 1, 1]})

df['result'] = (df.groupby('TYPE').apply(lambda g: f_map.get(g['TYPE'].iloc[0])(g['DATA']))
                  .reset_index(level = 0, drop = True))
```

[image]